# Scrapy spider not consistently terminating with use of CloseSpider extension

Tags: scrapy

i tried using `CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT` extension in the settings to kill the  spiders which are running beyond 3 hours.

```
CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT = 3 * 60 * 60
```

Although the spiders receive the close timeout request, It never actually stops the spider, which keeps on running.

Any ideas on what's wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your spider get the close timeout request, the extension seems to be working. It doesn't look like anything is wrong, but you might have to wait a bit before the spider fully closes, as he will first finish the already scheduled requests before shutting down completely.

Comment: That was my assumption as well, However, when the spider runs for more than a day with a timeout of 3 hours. I'm assuming something is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I confirm that after `CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT` - scrapy will stop to schedule new requests and it will continue execute already scheduled requests after `CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT`. Also you can check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55877309/10884791) - calling `os._exit(0)`

Comment: Shouldn't take that long indeed. did you define any close_spider methods in the pipelines/extensions? or an image/file download pipeline that is blocking? you can also try to use telnet (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/telnetconsole.html) when it looks blocked to see whether you have any progress in the queues

Comment: @WimHermans I happen to have the same issue and I do have a `close_spider` function in the item pipeline which performs some requets and DB r/w. why did you suggest the reason might be because of this?