# how to stop yielding of scrapy spider within for loop if a certain condition is met?

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy, scrapy

I want to get JSON response with a link using proxies but when i gather all proxies and loop through them, i get the valid JSON file after 2 to 4 attempts and now i want to quit if this condition is met.

But my spider still runs after trying to close when my condition mets or after getting "response 200".
I have tried sys.exit() and raise CloseSpider(reason) but nothing works for me.
Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import json
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
import sys

class ScrapyProxy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapy_proxy'
    start_urls = ['https://free-proxy-list.net']
    
    headers = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
    }
    
    def parse(self, response):
        table = response.css('table')
        rows = table.css('tr')
        cols = [row.css('td::text').getall() for row in rows]
        
        proxies = []
        
        for col in cols:
            if col and col[4] == 'elite proxy' and col[6] == 'yes':
                proxies.append('https://' + col[0] + ':' + col[1])
            
        print('proxies:', len(proxies))
        
        for proxy in proxies[0:5]:
            print(proxy)
            
            url = 'https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id=2426&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2'
            
            yield scrapy.Request(url, dont_filter=True, headers=self.headers, meta={'proxy': proxy}, callback=self.check_response)
            
         
    def check_response(self, response):
        print('\n\nRESPONSE:', response.status)
        try:
            data = json.loads(response.body)
            if data['items']:
                print(f'Received data with: {len(data["items"])} items.')
                # HERE I WANT TO CLOSE MY SPIDER
                # self.close(reason='Closign spider')
                # sys.exit('Exiting from the spider')
                # raise CloseSpider(reason='Closing the spider')
        except:
            print(f'got error in url {response.url}')

# run spider
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(ScrapyProxy)
process.start()
```

This is a standalone spider.
Please help me to terminate this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try this `os._exit(0)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to make my script stop when some urls are scraped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792062/unable-to-make-my-script-stop-when-some-urls-are-scraped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why `raise CloseSpider` doesn't work. <s>According to the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#closespider) it should.</s> see Georgiys comment

The reason why sys.exit does not work is probably that it is caught by twisted.
You could try to get the reactor and stop it

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
...
reactor.stop()
```

if that doesn't work try `reactor.crash()`

Comment: No. In [CloseSpider extension docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider) (not in CloseSpider exCeption docs mentioned in your answer) there is a note: When a certain closing condition is met, requests which are currently in the downloader queue (up to CONCURRENT_REQUESTS requests) are still processed. - exact this thing happened.