# How to stop Scrapy crawler from executing immediately?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using Scrapy framework for crawling some websites. I want to stop crawling immediately after a flag I decide. In my pipeline I stop the crawler like this:

```
spider.crawler.engine.close_spider(self, reason='My reason')
```

It stops when I want but it doesn't stop executing the code until it sends requests on the urls remaining in the connectionpool and I don't want that. How can I stop it immediately, is there a way to clear the urls from the connectionpool?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to scrapy [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.4/topics/extensions.html?highlight=closespider#module-scrapy.extensions.closespider) `close_spider` stop scheduling new requests and it does not stop crawling process immediately. In your case close_spider worked exactly as documented.
2. The only way I know to stop crawling immediately is to use `os.exit` like on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55877309/10884791).