# Is there a way to stop a Scrapy spider immediately as it fulfills a certain condition

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I want my running spider to be closed **immediately without processing any scheduled requests**, I've tried the following approaches to no avail,

- Raising CloseSpider in callback functions
- Calling spider.crawler.engine.close_spider(spider, 'reason') in a downloader middleware

The script is automated as it runs several spiders in a loop. I want the running spider to be closed instantly when it meets a certain condition and the program to be continued with the rest of the spiders inside the loop.

Is there a way to drop the requests from the scheduler queue?

I have included a snippet where i'm trying to terminate the spider

```
class TooManyRequestsMiddleware:
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if response.status == 429:
            spider.crawler.engine.close_spider(
                spider,
                f"Too many requests!, response status code: {response.status}
            )
        elif 'change_spotted' in list(spider.kwargs.keys()):
            print("Attempting to close down the spider")
            spider.crawler.engine.close_spider(spider, "Spider is terminated!")
        return response
```

Comment: Can you share this part of the code?

Comment: @SuperUser shared my downloader middleware snippet

Comment: CloseSpider should work so I tried it with your code and it was ok, did you remember to add the middleware to your settings?

Comment: yeah it works. though it takes time to close the spider, in the meantime few requests from scheduled spider will still go through the pipeline. i want the spider to be closed immediately as it meets the given condition. thanks!

Comment: @naru22to . This issue can be solved by usage of [`os._exit(0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55877309/10884791)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to make my script stop when some urls are scraped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792062/unable-to-make-my-script-stop-when-some-urls-are-scraped)