# Spider doesn't stop

Tags: scrapy

My spider is supposed to stop after the first 404. However, it doesn't.

```
################ 404 ################
Enter LAST PK IN DATABASE
################ 404 ################
Enter LAST PK IN DATABASE
################ 200 ################
################ PK:  6 ################
################ 200 ################
################ PK:  7 ################
################ 404 ################
Enter LAST PK IN DATABASE
################ 200 ################
################ PK:  5 ################
################ 200 ################
################ PK:  9 ################
################ 200 ################
```

Here the parse function:

```
class EventSpider(Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]  # TODO: Move to middleware?
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.someurl.com/api-internal/v1/events/%s/?format=json' % page for page in range(1,100)]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Accept X 404 error until stop processing

        print("################", response.status, "################")
        if response.status == 200:
            test = json.loads(response.body)
            print("################ PK: ", test.get("pk"), "################")
        elif response.status == 404:
            print("Enter LAST PK IN DATABASE")
            raise CloseSpider("404")
```

Comment: so what is the code that calls parse doing?

Comment: That's handled directly by Scrapy through its `Spider` class. I didn't modify anything there so far.

Comment: I now added the full Class

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331428/close-a-scrapy-spider-when-a-condition-is-met-and-return-the-output-object

Comment: Scrapy does not end immediately, it first handles all previously-started requests, which with the default concurrency is 8 per domain (16 total).