# How can I stop Scrapy CrawlSpider when it reach a specific time/certain total links for a particular domain?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have 50k company Homepage URLs from where I need to collect all Links to a certain depth and then identify relevant URLs by NLP Techniques.
I am using Scrapy Crawlspider to Extract all the links.
below is a snippet of my code.

```
Crawl_links.py    

    start_urls=[]
    allowed_domains=[]
    df=pd.read_excel("xyz.xlsx")

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(tags='a'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': '4',
    }   

    for url in df['URL'][:101]:            
        parent_url=formaturl(url)
        start_urls.append(parent_url)
        allowed_domains.append(tldextract.extract(parent_url).domain + ".com") 

Settings.py

  AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED = True
  DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
  SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
  SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
  AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
  AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 0.1
  AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 5
  CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 101
```

But for some cases, it goes into the product/news articles links list and then takes 2-3 days to crawls all links, which I don’t want.

How can I stop Scrapy CrawlSpider crawling/following the links when it reached a specific time or certain total links for a particular domain?

Also, suggest in the comments if there are any ways to improve anything here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38331428/939364

Comment: thanks for sharing the above link. but here I need to stop/close spider for a particular domain from start URLs and continue crawling for other links from start URLs.

Comment: Oh. For that you should probably create a custom download middleware.